# Select dynamic range without header

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select all rows in the range A2:BG2 if there are data present in column B. Row 2 is a header.

This *almost* works:

```
Set rng = Range("A2:BG2").Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
rng.Select
```

But it includes in the selection a blank row following the last row with data in B. For example, I have data in B2:B6 but this selects rows 2-7. Offset seems to just shift the whole dynamic range around. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your

```
Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
```

Where you are counting used rows from A1(1st row) but your range is starting from A2(2nd row)
so it will add extra blank row in the bottom. Hence to get rid that simply substract the row which you have counted unnecessarily.

```
Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
```

Final Code will be

```
Set rng = Range("A2:BG2").Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row - 1)
rng.Select
```

Hope this helps your puzzle .